# How can I configure WCF communication from one PC to another?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created WCF client/ server applications using calculator demo as mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx

When I bring up the WCF server in my PC (named PC1), I am able to open http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service using internet explorer.

I am now trying to test it from another PC (named PC2). So changed the URI to http://PC1:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service , and restarted the WCF server on PC1. I am able to open page http://PC1:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service from PC1, but I am not able to open that URL from PC2. It says page not found. I have checked communication between PC1 and PC2 using ping command, it pings fine.

Can someone please tell if I need to configure something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to open up port 8000 on the server

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-a-port-in-Windows-Firewall